# angular.json not migrated to angular v12 after upgrading nx workspace to v12 as well

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

Is it expected that the `angular.json` file of an nx workspace is not migrated to angular v12 after upgrading to worspace to v12?

Getting some warning in `angular.json` now and after generating a new application, the configuration looks slightly different to previous apps generated using nx.